# launch wireshark in linux

Tags: linux, wireshark

I have wireshark-1.2.15-2.el6_2.1.x86_64.rpm installed on CentOS. I was hoping to see a command like "wireshark", but couldnt find it. How do i launch wireshark? After querying the rpm, following components are installed. How do i launch the typical wireshark UI?

> /usr/sbin/capinfos
>   /usr/sbin/dftest
>   /usr/sbin/dumpcap
>   /usr/sbin/editcap
>   /usr/sbin/mergecap
>   /usr/sbin/randpkt
>   /usr/sbin/rawshark
>   /usr/sbin/tethereal
>   /usr/sbin/text2pcap
>   /usr/sbin/tshark

UPDATE: I needed to install wireshark-gnome for the UI.

Comment: Yeah that is an acient version of wireshark. You might want to search the 3rd party yum repositories for something newer. Current version is 1.8.3.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple packages for Wireshark. The base package provides command-line functions only.  There's also a wireshark-gnome package that includes the UI.  Install that one, or wireshark-gtk+ to get the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

From root:

```
./user/sbin/tshark -i interface > file.txt
```

This feature provides similar functionality to the conventional wireshark UI, but can be run like tcpdump on the console